# How to disable WebP images in Chrome?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, jpeg, image-conversion

Google Chrome sometimes takes a .jpg image and converts it to a .webp file.

The problem is that when I save this image to file, I cannot open the file. I have tried manually changing the extension of the file to ".jpg", but the file is still unreadable (without the use of external software).

Is there a way to completely disable .webp images in Chrome?

If not, is there an easy way or workaround to save an image that is presented as a WebP image, as a JPEG? The [solution provided here](http://webtrickz.com/saving-webp-image-files-in-jpg-or-png-format-on-google-chrome/) does not work for me, as my URL contains no "-rw" suffix.

<sub>OS X El Capitan, version 10.11.6.</sub>

Comment: I haven't used this extension so can't speak on how well it works, but you may want to give this a try: [Save Image As Type - Chrome Webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-image-as-type/ibcmpbjdpbkbdgejlchkllfiagebgbjp)

Comment: @n8te I will use the extension if there is no other alternative. But I always prefer native solutions, as I don't need yet another extension taking some of my computer's memory.

Comment: Yeah, I hear ya. That's why I didn't put it as an actual answer. But looking around I don't think there is native solution. But maybe someone else will come along and suggest a useful trick to get the job done.

Comment: I *specifically* recall you could just modify a small portion of the URI and the iamge will load in its original/alternative format?

Answer (score 8):

## Open-source solutions

[WebP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebP) is an image format currently developed by Google, based on technology acquired with the purchase of On2 Technologies.

If the [`User-Agent` field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) in your [HTTP(S) request header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) reveals you are using a recent browser, [content delivery network (CDN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) servers may serve original `.jpg` or `.png` images in this new WebP format to reduce data traffic. Nonetheless, these served image files will keep their original file extension; what is truly misleading.

On GNU/Linux systems, one solution consists in downloading the original image file using either the `wget` or `curl` command.

Several Google Chrome extensions offer a way to save images served as WebP in another image format. However, only one extension is **open-source** software; which is [**Save  image as Type**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-image-as-type/gabfmnliflodkdafenbcpjdlppllnemd).

This and all other similar extensions have one annoying drawback, though.
Between saves, these extensions **do not recall the directory** to which the previous image was saved. This may or may not be due to Google's sand-boxing policy concerning extensions. Anyhow, I opened a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/cuixiping/Save-Image-as-Type/issues/7) about it.

[image: Save image as Type]

Answer (score 7):

Method 1 provided by @Darius half works, but needs to be combined with a second modification. Changing the User-Agent alone does not fully solve the problem as the image server may also look at the HTTP "Accept" Request Header that lists the file formats the browser is compatible with. For chrome, the default Accept Header is "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8". Removing the image/webp format from that list and changing the User-Agent solves the problem. To do this:

1. Install the chrome extension [ModHeader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj?hl=en). Use that to change the "Accept" Heder to "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8".
2. Install [User-Agent Switcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg/related) and change to a browser such as Internet Explorer 9 that does not support webp. So that this does not break your internet viewing experience across the web, you may want to use the "Permanent Spoof List" feature by right clicking the extension icon and selecting "Options". This allows you to change the user-agent only on certain websites.

Comment: Very useful, nice find

Comment: There's no need to install User-Agent Switcher, because ModHeader can already be used to modfiy the User-Agent header.

Comment: The ModHeader extension recently became ad-injecting malware

Answer (score 5):

I found a possible solution to this. I simply added a question mark (?) to the end of the url and was able to download the image. So for example:

https://www.fritolay.com/sites/fritolay.com/files/2019-08/Desk-Where-to-Buy.jpg
This link downloads with webp extention when i go to "save image as"

https://www.fritolay.com/sites/fritolay.com/files/2019-08/Desk-Where-to-Buy.jpg?
This link downloads as jpg when I "save image as"

Please test and confirm is this works for anyone else.

Comment: Your solution worked!

Comment: This workaround doesn't always work.

Comment: Not working for me

Comment: perfect! works for me - if file is served as png it is saved as png - as it should be - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Chrome does not change images from JPEG to WebP - the images are served in WebP format from the website you're browsing. The web designer chose to serve images in WebP format because they're smaller than JPEG, so they load faster and use less of your bandwidth. It's better for everyone but not many programs can view WebP images at present, which can be a problem if you save a WebP image and then want to open it on your computer.

The good news is that you don't need to convert the WebP image to JPEG (or PNG or GIF) to view it. Chrome can display WebP images (as can Firefox, Opera and Edge browsers), which means you can simply open the .webp file in Chrome. In Chrome, click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to open the file or just drag and drop the file into Chrome.

If you want to edit the WebP image that you downloaded, you can open it in Photoshop and some other image editors (e.g. GIMP or MS Paint). More and more programs are adding support for WebP images, so in the future you'll have a wider choice of programs for viewing and editing WebP.

If you really need to convert the WebP image into a JPEG and you don't have a program to do that, you can upload the image to a converter service such as this:

https://ezgif.com/webp-to-jpg

Answer (score 1):

You can use cURL (which is included since Windows 10, as far as I know / macOS and OSX are shipped with cURL too) or the Windows PowerShell:

**cURL**

```
curl --output image.jpg --url https://domain.tld/image.jpg
```

**PowerShell**

```
Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile image.jpg -Uri https://domain.tld/image.jpg
```

If you don't have either of them, you can do it directly in your browser. Looks harder than it is:

1. Open a new tab / window and enter address `about:blank` to open an
   empty page
2. Press F12 to open developer console, go to tab "Console",
   enter `document.write('<a href="https://domain.tld/image.jpg">download</a>');` (change `https://domain.tld/image.jpg` to the URL of the image you want to save) and press
   enter
3. Right-click on newly appeared link and click on "Save Link As..." to download the original image instead of the WEBP

The reason why the server serves images in the WEBP format is because your browser tells the server that it supports images in the request:

[image: Browser request]

I don't know exactly why the server then decides to serve the image in the WEBP format, but I assume that it runs some kind of plugin or a built-in function to automatically convert images into this smaller file format if it detects that the client (browser) supports it by sending "image/webp" in the "Accept:" header.

You'll have this effect in every browser which supports and sends this info in the request header (like Firefox). Omitting sending this info will prevent the server from serving images in the WEBP format. For example, requesting an image through PHP or one of the above methods will give you the original file, because they don't include this info in their request.

Answer (score 0):

None of those methods works 100% but it gave me an idea how to make it 100% working. Simply download [Chromium Portable v61](https://sourceforge.net/projects/crportable/files/ChromiumPortable_61.0.3153.0.paf.exe/download). It does not require installation and it does not support webp =)

Comment: be sure to be in a really hardened environment or in a computer/network you don't care about security at all, using any very old browser will leave you easily exposed to severe security exploits